# How can i efficiently turn columns into 0 based on filter criteria?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

As mentioned in the title, how can I convert column into 0 based on the list of columns. I need to convert any column into 0 after first 3 column from from the list matches to 1.

for instance

list1 =["a","c","d","e","b"]

df=

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   1   0   1   1
1   0   0   0   1   1
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   1   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   1   1   1   1
```

what I want is :

```
    a   b   c   d   e
0   1   0   0   1   1
1   0   0   0   1   1
2   0   0   0   0   0
3   1   1   1   0   0
4   0   0   0   0   0
5   1   0   1   1   0
```

Currently, I am looping through each line and list. As this data frame gets bigger, it will take longer and longer so I wanted to see if there is an efficient way to do this.

My current code is:

```
a=np.random.randint(2, size=(6, 5))
df=pd.DataFrame(a,columns=["a","b",'c','d',"e"])
filterlist=["a","c",'d','e','b']

%%timeit
counter=1
for eachindex in df.index:
    for item in filterlist:
        if  (df.iloc[eachindex][item])==1:
            counter=counter+1
            if counter>4:
                df.loc[eachindex,item]=0
    counter=1
```

Timing is :

```
2.7 ms ± 60.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do with `reindex` and `cumsum` , then `mask` back

```
df.mask(df.reindex(columns=filterlist).cumsum(1).gt(3),0)
Out[620]: 
   a  b  c  d  e
0  1  0  0  1  1
1  0  0  0  1  1
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  1  1  1  0  0
4  0  0  0  0  0
5  1  0  1  1  0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. This is significantly faster than my approach. I will accept this as soon as I am allowed

Comment: @Sam yw :-) happy coding

Comment: Wen, If I had to only change 0 from that list and not touch other column. How can I do that?

Comment: @Sam I am not sure I get you , so when the condition meet  and if the original value is 0 you will do that change right ?

Comment: @Sam `df.mask(df.eq(0)&(df.reindex(columns=filterlist).cumsum(1).gt(3)),0)`

Comment: Wen, lets say that df has another column F. I want that f values to stay intact. I will accept this answer. Since you gave me the answer for my original question.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sam then in your filter list just do not include F `filterlist`